# how can I store data of data tree in firebase? for android studio project

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to store data of data tree for my android project data tree using Java or Kotlin programming language, like following,

```
"posts": {
  "typeScript": {
    "metrics": {
      "views" : 1200000,
      "likes" : 251000,
      "shares": 1200,
    },
    "title" : "TypeScript Functions",
    "author": "tim",
  },
  "android": {
    "metrics": {
      "views" : 900000,
      "likes" : 117000,
      "shares": 144,
    },
    "title" : "Android app can developed by android studio or flutter",
    "author": "scott",
  }
}
```

plz, help me.

Comment: What is wrong with this database structure?

Comment: i unable to store this type of data using java HashMap structure

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you tell us which is your structure data? class~?
typescript and android are 2 class or only 1?

```
private final  DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

private DatabaseReference typeListReference = databaseReference.child("typeScript");

private DatabaseReference androidListReference = 
    databaseReference.child("android");   

private void writeNewAndroid(String views, String likes, String share, String title, String others)
        {
            try {
                Android android = new Android (views, , likes, share, title, others);
                androidListReference.child("metrics").setValue(android );
            }catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a field type in Firebase called Object. You can use that for metrics fields.

[image: Try this structure]